# Odoo 9 Module to V10

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have a version 9 modue that works in V9. I am trying to get it to install in V10 and getting an error. The error happens when creating a security group. I also tried following from the maintainer tools Migration to V10.

```
>    Replace openerp imports to odoo.
> 
>     Rename __openerp__.py to __manifest__.py
> 
>     Replace select = True by index = TrueReplace string selectors in XML by name (if possible) or other attribute selector or even another
> equivalent path/reference. For example, change <group string="x"
> position="after"> by <group name="x" position="after">Remove <data>
> and </data> in xml files if noupdate="0"
> 
>     Replace the <openerp>/</openerp> tags in xml files by <odoo>/</odoo>.
> 
>     Don't use @api.one with @api.onchange or it will crash.
> 
>     ...
```

Below is the error

```
File "/home/jason/git/odoo10/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1028, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ParseError: "<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: "External ID not found in the system: base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads" while evaluating
"[(4,ref('base.group_user')),                                         (4,ref('account.group_account_invoice')),                                         (4,ref('stock.group_stock_user')),                                         (4,ref('base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads'))]"" while parsing /home/jason/git/customaddons/layby_order/security/layby_security.xml:5, near
<record id="group_layby_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Layby User</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_sales_management"/>
        <field name="comment">This is applicable for Layby User.</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user')),                                         (4,ref('account.group_account_invoice')),                                         (4,ref('stock.group_stock_user')),                                         (4,ref('base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads'))]"/>
    </record>
```

layby_security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="group_layby_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Layby User</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_sales_management"/>
        <field name="comment">This is applicable for Layby User.</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user')),
                                        (4,ref('account.group_account_invoice')),
                                        (4,ref('stock.group_stock_user')),
                                        (4,ref('base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads'))]"/>
    </record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_layby_order,layby.order,model_layby_order,group_layby_user,1,1,1,0
access_layby_order_line,layby.order.line,model_layby_order_line,group_layby_user,1,1,1,1
```

If i stop the server and start it again then try the install the first error I get is

```
    File "/home/jason/git/customaddons/layby_order/layby.py", line 147
        date_order = fields.Date.context_today(self)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

after that if I install I get the Parse error External ID not found. I am thinking the reason I am getting that is because the install is stopping on line 147 `date_order = fields.Date.context_today(self)`but I have no idea why.

Updated

Still stopping on line 147

```
date_order = fields.Date.context_today(self))
```

after changing to          `sales_team.group_sale_salesman_all_leads`

original error is gone but now get

```
raise Exception(_('Module loading %s failed: file %s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
Exception: Module loading layby_order failed: file layby_order/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 No matching record found for external id 'model_layby_order' in field 'Object'
Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)
No matching record found for external id 'model_layby_order_line' in field 'Object'
Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

OCA's guide to migrate modules from v9 to v10 is mostly sufficient, except that it does not mention that several security groups that used to be prefixed by `base` have been moved / modularised to their respective modules, such as `base.group_hr_user` and as you have seen in your case, `base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads`.

To solve your first issue, change your ref `base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads` to `sales_team.group_sale_salesman_all_leads` in `layby_security.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="group_layby_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Layby User</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_sales_management"/>
        <field name="comment">This is applicable for Layby User</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user')),
                                    (4,ref('account.group_account_invoice')),
                                    (4,ref('stock.group_stock_user')),
                                    (4,ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman_all_leads'))]"/>
    </record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

For your second issue, if `date_order` is a field you are adding to your class, do this instead:

```
date_order = fields.Date(default=fields.Date.context_today)
```

Otherwise, if you are actually declaring a variable instead of a new field, your syntax looks OK and Odoo 10 is still using `fields.Date.context_today()`.

You can [look it up on github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/search?l=Python&q=context_today&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

---

EDIT: (after question was updated)

The error might be because you are missing the model declaration in your `res.groups` record.

Could you try adding `<field name="model_id" ref="model_layby_order"/>` in layby_security.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="group_layby_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Layby User</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_layby_order"/>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_sales_management"/>
        <field name="comment">This is applicable for Layby User</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user')),
                                    (4,ref('account.group_account_invoice')),
                                    (4,ref('stock.group_stock_user')),
                                    (4,ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman_all_leads'))]"/>
    </record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: I updated my original question. I am getting a different error now ir.model.access.csv could not be processed: Still stopping on date_order = fields.Date.context_today(self))

Comment: I get  raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: layby_order.model_layby_order" while parsing /home/jason/git/customaddons/layby_order/security/layby_security.xml:5, near

Comment: Can you also post your `__openerp__.py` file?